# grpc забсрок к докеру

Tags: c#

Привет всем у меня есть dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app


EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["CSI.Individuals.Api/CSI.Individuals.Api.csproj", "CSI.Individuals.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CSI.Individuals.Api/CSI.Individuals.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CSI.Individuals.Api"
RUN dotnet build "CSI.Individuals.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CSI.Individuals.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CSI.Individuals.Api.dll"]
```

запускаю проект через вижлу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

создаю  канал

```
 _channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:32802");
```

происходит следующая ошибка
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
можете подсказать или направить что мне надо чтобы сделать

Comment: а проверьте, пожалуйста, логи докер контейрена, т.к. там банально может запуститься только на 80 порту, без 443.

Comment: т.к. картинка показывает какие порты замаплены в докере, но не на каких фактически слушает сервер